# Why does this object get populated only at the second call?

Tags: angular, typescript

This is the method that I created:

```
getUser(endpoint: string, email: string) { 
  const url = this.envConfigurationService.baseEndpoint + '/' + conf.apiPrefix + '/' + endpoint + email; 
  this.loadingService.loadingOn(); 
  return this.http.get(url).pipe( 
    finalize(() => this.loadingService.loadingOff()), 
    catchError((err) => { 
      this.manageError(err); 
      return throwError(err); 
    }), 
    tap(() => this.toastrService.success('OK')), 
 ); 
}
```

and here's how I call it in the component.ts:

```
searchUser() { 
    this.backendIntegrationService.getUser('user?code=', encodeURIComponent(this.form.value.email)).subscribe({ 
      next: (res) => { 
        if (res['result'] === 'OK') { 
            this.userresponse = res['body']; 
            this.usermessage = res['message'] 
        } 
        else { 
          this.errorResponse = res; 
        } 
      }, 
      error: err => { 
        this.errorResponse = err; 
      } 
    }); 
    console.log(this.userresponse) 
    this.entityConfiguration.inputFields.forEach(field => { 
      console.log(this.userresponse) 
      let value = null; 
       
      value = this.userresponse[field.name]; 
      if (field.disabled) { 
        this.formControls[field.name] = this.fb.control({value: value, disabled: true}); 
      } else { 
        this.formControls[field.name] = this.fb.control(value); 
      } 
    }); 
    this.form = this.fb.group(this.formControls); 
  }
```

For some reason, the object ***this.userresponse*** only get populated at the second call (second time I push the search user button), even though I get the values from the backend at the first time.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an async operation. You call your service and then proceed with your function. Inside your subscribe block the variable will be set but at a later time. In the meantime the code has reached your `console.log()` statement and prints out an undefined value (as it is undefined at that point).

You'll want to wait for the call to complete (ie. your `next` block) before processing the response.

You mention that the variable is defined the second time around. Which it is-- but it's the response from the first call.